# Remove duplicates from a list in an Arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, hashset

I checked many examples but i could not applied for my variables.
I have a ArratyList Of lists of Strings.

```
ArrayList<List<String>> bulkUploadList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

and it's look like this:

[id, title, tags, descriptions]

```
[4291483113.0000000000000, Camden, camdentown;london, NoValue]
[4292220054.0000000000000, IMG_2720, NoValue, NoValue]
[4292223824.0000000000000, IMG_2917, london;camdentown, NoValue]
[4292224728.0000000000000, IMG_2945, London;CamdenTown, NoValue]
```

I want to remove those rows which have the same titles and the same tags.
I do not know how work with HashSet since I have a ArrayList of List of Strings.

Comment: Why you have an arraylist of strings in the first place ? Create a class to hold this datas.

Comment: Would you please explain more, what do you mean by holding them in a class. It's the result of a selection query from DB and I am going to remove duplicates and store in another table in DB

Comment: Why are you doing duplication removal in Java? You have an RDBMS engine: use it!

Comment: 1-I am not professional i. 2- the order is important for me and based on which items are similar and based on which order I do different things as well and make a relationship tables for them.3-in case, there is a way, so I do not know how to do it!

Comment: You can remove duplicates on database by using 'distinct', 'group by' or something else

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have a question. for example I want to make a query that find those records of a user which the titles and tags are the same!and delete those!

Comment: it's not as easy as you say for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not best solution, but you can start with this:

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> bulkUploadList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();

    for(List<String> item : bulkUploadList) {
        String title = item.get(1);
        String tags = item.get(2);
        String uniqueString = (title + "#" + tags).trim().toUpperCase();

        if(!hashSet.contains(uniqueString)) {
            result.add(item);
            hashSet.add(uniqueString);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Filtered element " + uniqueString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added conversion to upper case and trim operation, thanks. We can also trim each of parameters separately

Comment: @EldarBudagov hi again. I have another question. I could removed those rows which have the same titles and tags and kept just one of those. How I can find which id in kept list corresponding which removed one?

Comment: Use HashMap instead of HashSet to retain binding between id and data

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments, you should create a class for the data, make that class implement equals(), and then use HashSet to remove dups. Like this.

```
class Foo {
String id;
String title;
String tags;
String description;

public boolean equals(Foo this, Foo other) {
   return this.id.equals(other.id) 
      && this.title.equals(other.title)
      && etc.
}
```

then you can remove dups with

```
 Set<Foo> set = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>(list);
```

as Sets do not allow duplication, and the equals() method is used to check.

You should use a linkedHashSet here because you want to preserve the order (according to a comment you made on elsewhere).

You should also implement a hashcode() method consistent with equals().

Comment: thanks for writing that I am going to use it as well to learn how to use it :)